# How to call method of a user control on Button click in MVVM. My User Control Display progress of Task using Dispatcher Helper

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

Actually, I am working on a migration project. I am migrating data from CSV to Database. I have developed an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern.

To display the progress of migration, I have used control and DispatcherHelper.

I have added a button in my User Control to cancel the migration process but I am not able to handle the click event using the MVVM pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a view and ViewModel as it's DataContext, so In you view model, create a command property using the RelayCommand.
Bind that command to the Cancel button.

Add a DependencyProperty to your User Control let's say: IsActive, and Bind it to the a Property on the ViewModel. On the first Command just set the property IsActive to false.

On the DependencyProperty IsActive, handle the Cancellation itself.

Comment: @user3488166, if I have answered your question please accept the answer as the correct one so that others may find it and learn from it as well :)

Comment: Well, to me this answer is wrong. Why should the OP accept your answer? Just because it is the only answer so far?

Comment: @Sir Rufo, If you have a concrete question regarding my solution, ask away, I will gladly explain. This is too basic, nothing fancy.